# Jaxb eclipse moxy Nullable in element and XmlAdapter with Map<String,Date>

Tags: jaxb, moxy

This is my code according the example:
I was looking for formatting the Date field inside a Map
but it throws this exception:

```
The object [{birthDate=1963-07-16 00:00:00.0}], of class [class org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentMap], could not be converted to [class it.cineca.jaxb.adapter.MyMapType].
```

Example

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public final class MyMapAdapter extends

   XmlAdapter<MyMapType,Map<String, Date>> {

   private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

   @Override
   public MyMapType marshal(Map<String, Date> arg0) throws Exception {
      MyMapType myMapType = new MyMapType();
      for(Entry<String, Date> entry : arg0.entrySet()) {
         MyMapEntryType myMapEntryType =
            new MyMapEntryType();
         myMapEntryType.key = entry.getKey();
         myMapEntryType.value = dateFormat.parse(entry.getValue().toString());
         myMapEntryType.value = entry.getValue();
         myMapType.entry.add(myMapEntryType);
      }
      return myMapType;
   }

   @Override
   public Map<String, Date> unmarshal(MyMapType arg0) throws Exception {
      HashMap<String, Date> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Date>();

      for(MyMapEntryType myEntryType : arg0.entry) {
         hashMap.put(myEntryType.key, myEntryType.value);
      }
      return hashMap;
   }

}



import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

public class MyMapEntryType {

   @XmlAttribute
   public String key;

   @XmlValue
   public Date value;

}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyMapType {

   public List<MyMapEntryType> entry = 
      new ArrayList<MyMapEntryType>();

}
```

this is the person-binding file

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <xml-bindings
        xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
        package-name="it.model"  xml-mapping-metadata-complete="true">
        <xml-schema
            element-form-default="QUALIFIED"/>
        <java-types>
            <java-type name="Person"  xml-accessor-type="NONE">
                <xml-root-element/>
                <xml-type prop-order="firstName lastName stringMap "/>
                <java-attributes>
nillable="true"/>
                    <xml-element java-attribute="stringMap" name="string-map" nillable="true"/>
                    <xml-element java-attribute="dateMap" name="date-map" nillable="true">
                        <xml-java-type-adapter value="it.cineca.jaxb.adapter.MyMapAdapter" />
                    </xml-element>                  
          <xml-element java-attribute="positionCurrentSet" name="position-current-set" nillable="true">
       <!-- UNLIKELY THIS DOESN'T PRODUCE EMPTY NODE -->
       <xml-null-policy xsi-nil-represents-null="true" empty-node-represents-null="true" null-representation-for-xml="EMPTY_NODE" is-set-performed-for-absent-node="true" />
                    </xml-element>                  
                </java-attributes>
            </java-type>
    </java-types>
    </xml-bindings>
```

So How Could I solve It?
I tried following the http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html
post but I don't find the bug it's the same logic.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the parameter types reversed in MyMapAdapter.  From the JAXB javadocs:

> public abstract class XmlAdapter<ValueType,BoundType>
>
> BoundType - The type that JAXB doesn't know how to handle. An adapter is written to allow this type to be used as an in-memory representation through the ValueType.
>
> ValueType - The type that JAXB knows how to handle out of the box.

Try changing your class signature to `MyMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Map<String, Date>, MyMapType>`, and swap your marshal and unmarshal methods.

Hope this helps,

Rick

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work I answered with my attempt above.  I was to trying to solve the same problem that I wrote in the precedent question to get empty tag for null property. I tried this: <!-- UNLIKELY THIS DOESN'T PRODUCE EMPTY NODE --> <xml-null-policy xsi-nil-represents-null="true" empty-node-represents-null="true" null-representation-for-xml="EMPTY_NODE" is-set-performed-for-absent-node="true" /> </xml-element> but it doesn't work

Comment: I believe that I'll use the same approach for the Map<String,String> and I'll solve in this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931235/jaxb-eclipse-moxy-nullable-value-and-retrieve-only-a-specified-key-in-a-map/16063219#16063219